# GET Method Play

Tags: javascript, java, plot, playframework, get

I have a controller in Play Framework 1.3.x in which I have defined the following:

```
public static void plots(Long id) {
    //... (Code goes here)
    render(list); //Data to render
}
```

And then in a separate html file in the views folder I want to "display" the result from another html file. I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get("plots", id, function(${list}){ //I want to give the list needed by the file plots.html
       $("#result").html(list); //And then in "result" show the plots obtained 
        })
    }, 1000);   
    </script>
...
 <span id="result"></span>
```

But it does not display anything at all. This plots file just needs this list and then does a plot with the data but I'm pretty sure I'm not writing code in the right way, I mean, I'm not giving the function the right syntaxis or parameters. Any ideas? Thanks!

PS: My routes file

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index



# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

Comment: Make sure you have included jquery in your HTML head tag

Comment: I think your problem is that the URL is not valid for jQuery. `"plots"` is unknown to him and not a valid URL. I think you need to take a look at Reverse Routing https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/routes#reverse

Comment: This is my routes file:

# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index



# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}

Comment: Well, I'd better edit my post and write them there in order to read them better.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define route

```
GET     /plots                                       Application.plots(id:Long)
```

and

```
$.get("/plots", id, function(${list})
```

or according to your code

```
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

use

```
 $.get("Application/plots", id, function(${list}){ //Application is your controller name
```

but i will suggest to use first one

Comment: I get the following error:

SyntaxError: missing variable name
 

...get("/plots", id, function([Sample[3982], Sample[3983], Sample[3984], Sa...